# Is it possible to produce a blur map of a render instead of having baked motion blur?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm looking for a way in which I can render an image in Blender with no motion blur, and separately render a map per frame that dictates blur from the motion information of the meshes in the scene.

Comment: You could use the vector blur node in compositing? Would that work for you? I'm not sure if that is what you want, so I am not directly answering.